# How to reverse user input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a script that takes the user input and reverses the whole input. 
for example if the user inputs "London" it will be printed as "nodnol" . I am currently being able to reverse the order of a certain number of letters but not being able to reverse the entire string .

Comment: `print raw_input().lower()[::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse it with the slicing syntax:

```
s = input("Enter a string: ")
print s[::-1]
```

```
Enter a string: London
nodnoL
```

Answer (score 1):

`print raw_input().lower()[::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that you cannot use any of the nice things that make Python a *soo* nice language, so here it is my low-key answer...

At the beginning, we have a string,

```
>>> ast = input('Tell me a word of your choice: ') # <--- "London"
```

We can compute its length using the `len` builtin

```
>>> last = len(ast) # <--- 6
```

now we want to index the string in reverse, the string indices are `0 ... 5` so we need the sequence `5 4 3 2 1 0`

```
>>> for i in range(last): print(last-1-i)
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Let's see that we can access the characters of the string in reverse using the indexing scheme above

```
>>> for i in range(last): print(ast[last-1-i])
n
o
d
n
o
L
```

Finally, we have to build the reversed string, using the `+` operator and starting from the null string

```
>>> rast = ""
>>> for i in range(last): rast += ast[last-1-i]
>>> print(rast)
nodnoL
>>>
```

To summarize

```
ast = input('Tell me a word of your choice: ')
last = len(ast)
rast = ""
for i in range(last):
    rast += ast[last-1-i]
```

Answer (score -1):

Using extended slice syntax: `'string_goes_here'[::-1]`

Example : `print('london'[::-1])`

[Online Compiler link](https://ideone.com/WxJTuW)

Extended Slices :

> Ever since Python 1.4, the slicing syntax has supported an optional
>   third `step'' or`stride'' argument. For example, these are all
>   legal Python syntax: L[1:10:2], L[:-1:1], L[::-1]. This was added to
>   Python at the request of the developers of Numerical Python, which
>   uses the third argument extensively. However, Python's built-in list,
>   tuple, and string sequence types have never supported this feature,
>   raising a TypeError if you tried it. Michael Hudson contributed a
>   patch to fix this shortcoming.

--[Reference](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
    s = input("Enter a string: ")
    s = s.lower()
    print s[::-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

string=input('Enter String: ')

print (string[::-1])

string: heaven
output:nevaeh